# Calling a New View by selecting a UITableView Row Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am having some issues with pulling up specific ViewControllers depending on which row is selected in my UITableView.  I have a table, which contains 3 sections, with 4 rows in each section.

When a row is selected I have it set to call a new view for each row, so 12 views in total to be called depending on which row is selected.  The issue is, that only the first 4 views are called, when I tap row number 5, it displays a new view, but it pulls up the first view.

I have set my UITableView up using the following code;

```
carbData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"What Are Carbs?",@"Why Do I Need Carbs?",@"Simple Vs. Complex",@"Fun Five Facts",nil];
    proteinData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"What is Protein?",@"Why Do I Need Protein?",@"Complete Vs. Incomplete",@"Fun Five Facts",nil];
    fatData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"What Are Fats?",@"Why Do I Need Fats?",@"Saturated Vs. Unsaturated",@"Fun Five Facts",nil];
    [self setTitle:@"Nutrition Table"];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.carbData count];
    return [self.proteinData count];
    return [self.fatData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) { cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }   
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
        cell.text = [carbData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(indexPath.section == 1)
        cell.text = [proteinData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.section == 2)
        cell.text = [fatData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0)
        return @"Carbohydrates";
    if (section ==1)
        return @"Protein";
    else if (section ==2)
        return @"Fats";
}
```

I then use the following code to determine which view is to be called, when a certain row is selected;

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        if ([[carbData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"What Are Carbs?"]) {
            CarbsView1 *controller = [[CarbsView1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"CarbsView1" bundle:nil];
            controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            [controller release];
        }
        if ([[carbData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Why Do I Need Carbs?"]) {
            CarbsView2 *controller = [[CarbsView2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"CarbsView2" bundle:nil];
            controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            [controller release];
        }
        if ([[carbData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Simple Vs. Complex"]) {
            CarbsView3 *controller = [[CarbsView3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"CarbsView3" bundle:nil];
            controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            [controller release];
        }
        if ([[carbData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Fun Five Facts"]) {
            CarbsView4 *controller = [[CarbsView4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"CarbsView4" bundle:nil];
            controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            [controller release];
        }
        if  ([[proteinData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"What is Protein?"]) {
            ProteinView1 *controller = [[CarbsView4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProteinView1" bundle:nil];
            controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
            [controller release];
        }
```

The app compiles and builds fine, everything works as i'd like it too, however when looking at the titles used, when I try and select "What is Protein?" is pulls up the view for "what are Carbs?" which is in the first if statement.

Any help would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What is Protein?" is in section 1, row 0.  "What are Carbs?" is in section 0, row 0.  Notice that your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you don't check the section number anywhere.  So when you tap section 1, row 0, your first if statement returns true.  I think you want something more like:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        //present appropriate view controller
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {

    } ...
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    } ...
} ...
```

Comment: You have literally just this second enriched my life. That worked perfectly, I knew it was something like that, but I couldn't figure out how to implement the rule. Thank you so much